# Light not affecting parts of an object

Tags: lighting, glass

I have a 16x16x16 "glass" cube made of cubes. Every individual cube has the following settings [image: cube settings]

Here there is a spot light shining on the bottom corner of the cube of cubes and it looks like only some of the smaller cubes get hit with the light. Moving the light around does not affect which cubes are illuminated - if i slide the light to the left, the cubes on the left side of the crumble stay black.

[image: cubes]

[image: left]

If it helps: to get here, I followed [this video](https://%5B!%5Bcube%20settings%5D%5B1%5D%5D%5B1%5D) for the initial glass cube and used array modifiers to get the 16x16x16. I wanted to delete certain cubes to make a crumbling effect so I followed another post suggesting **Separate by loose parts** and **Origin to Geometry**. Since there are so many layers of cubes, I don't expect light to permeate very far but what I would like is to have that slight glow where the light is actually hitting the cube to happen throughout the knocked out section of the bottom corner of the cube.

Sorry in advance, I'm very new to this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Probably the blend file would be the easiest way to solve this problem... because there are quite a few informations missing which could bring light into the dark (pun intended). For example, how large are these cubes? How bright is the spotlight (because it does not seem to affect the cubes at all, they get light from a secondary light source)? Are those cubes directly next to each other without any gap (Z-fighting)? What are your _Max Bounces_ settings under _Light Paths_ (especially _Total_, _Glossy_ and _Transmission_)? These are just the first probable issues that come to my mind.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thanks for the response! here is the blend file. i think everything is pretty big and bright <a href="<a href="https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/m2vnmqrvveqf5pmytkj7a/glassCube.blend?rlkey=28uw5xi79dblnk6dvt3q3z38j&dl=0">file</a>">file</a>

Comment: @Chris, thank you, here it is! https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/m2vnmqrvveqf5pmytkj7a/glassCube.blend?rlkey=28uw5xi79dblnk6dvt3q3z38j&dl=0

Comment: Please tell us which renderer you are using, as well.

Comment: @RobinBetts I'm using Cycles for the render engine

Comment: your spotlight is just very far away. either make it stronger or move the spotlight much nearer to the cube, then you will see that moving it makes a big difference. also keep in mind that a spotlight has a direction. So normally if you move it, check whether the direction still hits the cubes.

Comment: @Chris The spotlight is not the problem. It is just about 90 m away and has a _Power_ of 650.000 W. If you replace the glass cubes with a regular cube with default material, scaled to the size of the glass cubes, it gets lit like expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TLDR

There are some issues coming together in your scene, mostly all I mentioned before in the comments: The cubes are too close together, the *Glossy* and *Transmission* bounces are much too low and the origins are not set to the cubes' geometries.

### Long version: How to improve the scene

First of all, it is not the glass material itself as you can see in those separated cubes. Although, it is not ideal either (or at least not in this scene) as you can see in the following example.

I replaced all the small cubes with a single large cube and you can see it works. But since the *Roughness* is 0 and the faces you see from the camera are all angled to reflect the environment, if you take away the plane behind it and set the world to black, there is not much left to see on the front of the cube from the spotlight, since it does not reflect any light towards the camera. Only some internal reflections are visible:

[image: reflection angles]

Here you can already see the influence of the *Max Bounces* settings. You have set a *Total* of 146, but that does not really help anything if your *Glossy* and *Transmission* bounces are so low at 4 and 12. Especially when you have 16³ = 4096 cubes together, these bounce values are ridiculously small. Light gets reflected on the glossy surfaces inside a glass object very often, so I would at least set the *Glossy* value to 32, maybe even better to 64. It's just a subtle bit for one cube, but more important for the many later on. And while we're at it, increase *Transmission* to 64 or higher as well. This does not matter much on a single cube, but later with the myriads of cubes it will make a significant difference. Here a comparison for the *Glossy* bounces:

[image: glossy bounces]

Now move on to the next problem. Your cubes are directly touching each other, which means there are always two faces in the exact same location. The *Cycles* engine then cannot decide which face to show in front of the other and this can result in strange artifacts or completely black faces. This effect is sometimes called *Z fighting*.

I've created a cube made of 2³ = 8 smaller cubes, all directly face to face with each other. Instead of looking like cyan glass, they are looking not transparent at all, just black. And while you state in your question you would have set the *Origin to Geometry*, you must have made a mistake there - because all your cubes have their origin in one bottom corner (apart from those moved down). I'll show the rendered viewport now so you can see overlays. Watch the difference the origin point makes for Z fighting, because different origins help the render engine decide which faces to "prefer" (if you would not apply the *Array* modifier it would also be the same like having all origins in one corner), although the negative effect is only that strong like shown here if you have very low bounce values:

[image: origin points]

But although the origins are matching the geometry now and you increase the bounces like mentioned earlier, there are still a lot of dark areas (although these are only 8 cubes, not 4096). That is because Z fighting is not a matter of bounces, but doubled faces. So if you would - instead of setting the *Array* modifiers to a *Relative Offset* of 1, having each cube being exactly next to the others - use values that leave just a slight gap like e.g. 1.001, the result would be a lot different:

[image: slight gap between cubes]

With all that being said, let's go back to your original cubes. The main problem which makes them all black is the Z fighting and the incorrect origin points. For the distance between them you could either recreate them with a gap set in the *Array* modifiers or - if they do not have to be exactly 2×2×2 m - you could scale them down individually.

So first of all, select all cubes, right-click in the viewport and choose *Set Origin* > *Origin to Geometry* (there seem to be two cubes not separated, but that's no big deal in this case).

[image: set origins]

Then make sure you have set the *Transform Pivot Point* to *Individual Origins* and scale them down just a little bit like 99.9% of their size. To do that, press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>.999</kbd><kbd>Return</kbd>.

[image: scale down cubes]

Below now a comparison after scaling down the cubes, the left side is with your bounces' settings 4/12, the right side is my recommended 64/64. Maybe the change is not worth the render time, that's on you to decide. With *Max Samples* set to 500 and *Noise Threshold* 0.1, rendering the image at 1920×1080 took my PC 22 seconds for the left and 27 seconds for the right one.

[image: bounces comparison]

And if you are wondering about the still black areas in the "hole" on the corner, I found 53 duplicate cubes in there, and after deleting them all the render took 25 seconds and this is the final result:

[image: final result]

Comment: thank you so much for the thorough explanation and examples of how to fix!